# What is the difference between ReportService2005.asmx and ReportExecution2005.asmx Web Service Endpoints in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Does anyone know what the difference is between the two web service endpoints ReportService2005.asmx and ReportExecution2005.asmx in SQL Server Reporting Services? is there an article that I can go through? Thanks.

Comment: Note the differences between the different SQL Server versions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ReportExecution2005` endpoint allows developers to programmatically process and render reports in a report server. The WSDL for this endpoint is accessed through `ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl`.

The ReportService2005 Web service (`reportservice2005.asmx`) allows developers to programmatically manage objects in a report server.

Comment: The ReportService2005 and ReportService2006 endpoints are deprecated in SQL Server 2008 R2. The ReportService2010 endpoint includes the functionalities of both endpoints and contains additional management features.

Answer (score 9):

As Mitch says, `ReportExecution2005` is for executing reports, handling drilldown, rendering, etc. and `ReportService2005` is used for creating things (data sources, subscriptions, even reports), as well as updating, deleting, querying, etc.

Two handy references are the MSDN method listings for [ReportExecutionService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice_methods%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) (ReportExecution2005 web service endpoint) and [ReportingService2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc282570%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) (ReportService2005 web service endpoint).

Don't confuse these with the `ReportService2006` endpoint, which is used if you have SSRS configured for Sharepoint integrated mode.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

**ReportService2005**

1. Enables you to manage a report server and its contents including server settings, security, reports, subscriptions, and data sources.
2. Can be accessed by: `http://servername:port/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl`

**ReportExecution2005**

1. Enables report execution
2. Can be accessed by: `http://servername:port/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl`